# What herbs are known as bad for deer deterrents?

Tags: deer

my garden is going to be directly in a deer path this year, and was wondering what types of herbs are good, and bad for telling deer they don't want to be in the area? I could go to the local butcher shop and ask for a bucket of animal blood if needed to tell animals it is a "kill zone"

Comment: There is not much a deer won't eat when hungry, eg, deer will nibble poinsettia leaves. I found human hair ( from beauty/barber shop) will deter rabbits; I think that would be worth a try.